# Top k closest pairs in a set of million 128-dimensional points

Tags: python, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded, clustering

I have a set of 1 million points in 128-dimensional space. Among all trillion pairs of the points in the set, I need to get a subset of 100 million pairs whose cosine distances are less than that of every pair outside the subset.

I tried measuring cosine distances of all trillion pairs, sort them and get first 100 million of sorted pairs. But this program is estimated to take few years in single thread.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

points = load_points_list()         # List of points, where each point is tuple of 128 floats
M = len(points)                     # 1 million points

cosine_distances, pairs = [], []
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(M):
        cosine_distances.append(cosine(points[i], points[j]))
        pairs.append((i, j))

# Sort pairs based on cosine distances
cosine_distances, pairs = (list(s) for s in zip(*sorted(zip(cosine_similarities, pairs_indices))))

top_100_million_closest_pairs = pairs[:100000000]
```

Is there a more efficient algorithm or GPU-enabled acceleration for a problem at this scale?

Comment: Didn´t find anything implemented, but there are several [papers](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e968/38bde759b9dfa1f27436fb8cbe14ddf29b61.pdf) on the subject

Comment: [Another paper](https://people.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/k-closestnote.pdf)

Comment: Super computer?

Comment: @juvian The 1992 papers are particular to Chebyshev as distance metric. Although their complexity is a good O(nlogn + k),  I don't think they apply to cosine distance.

Comment: Given the current implementation doesn’t protect against `i==j`, the answer starts with the first 1 million points paired with themselves, for a cosine distance of zero.  The real work begins with finding the next 99 million closest non-identity pairs.

Comment: @jayadeepk note that euclidean distance and cosine [are related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146221/is-cosine-similarity-identical-to-l2-normalized-euclidean-distance/146279#146279)

Comment: @juvian, I didn't realize this relation before. Seems like nlogn can be achieved after all! Hope the large constants mentioned in the paper wouldn't bother much, especially when dimensions are as many as 128. I think this should be submitted as an answer.

Comment: @jayadeepk maybe this helps: https://code.fb.com/data-infrastructure/faiss-a-library-for-efficient-similarity-search/

Answer (score 2):

First, cut your work load in half.  You only need to consider pairs where `i < j`, so:

```
for i in range(M-1):
    for j in range(i+1, M):
        # ...
```

If you actually need both `(i, j)` and `(j, i)`, then you only need the 50 million closest pairs, and can duplicate & swap every pair in the list as the last step.   More savings!

Record & sort the first 100 million (50 million?) pairs.  Then, as new pairs are generated, if closer than the worst stored pair, use `bisect.bisect()` to find insertion spot, add the new pair, and kick out the worst pair.

Time: \$O(n^2 log k)\$, 
Space: \$O(k)\$, n is number of points, k is desired number of pairs.

Comment: Good observations, but will still take several years

Comment: @juvian, agree. Although logn is reduced to logk, the n^2 component still exists. It'd be best to avoid calculation and scanning of all cosine similarities. Also, I think bisection algorithm is hard to parallelize.

Comment: Bisecting is just for incremental insertions into the `k` closest.  If you partitioned the data into independent sets processed in parallel, you’d just need a merge-sorts, each \$O(k)\$, to combine the results. For instance, is the data was partitioned into 4 sets, A B C & D, you’d be able to process pairs AA, AB, AC, AD, BB, BC, BD, CC, CD & DD in parallel into 10 sets of k-nearest.  Then one 10-way merge-sort keeping only the k-nearest.  (You could parallelize this last step too.  Five parallel 2-way merge-sorts, followed by 2 more ...)

Answer (score 0):

You were given some points already, check each pair only once and keep the sorted list of short distanced pairs of the required length. This keeps complexity low.

When done with complexity you have a look at the measure itself. You did not show the imlementation or import of `cosine`. As you need comparability only you may optimize the measure, e. g. skip calculation of costly square roots.

Next you make use of dynamic programming. Inside `cosine` most probably there are expressions that are constant for a certain `i`. Cache those intermediate results.

Finally you try to have cache locality regarding processor, memory and harddisk. Partition your problem to chunks that fit to memory and to make ideal use of dynamic programming.

Comment: Updated import scipy.spatial.distance.cosine in question now.